# Why doesn't work NSOperationQueue.mainQueue?

Tags: swift, nsoperationqueue

I have this code

```
    @IBAction func joinButtonTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
        self.joinButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.resultLogIn.text = "Checking data..."
        })


    var response = NetworkManager.sharedInstance.SendRequest("<Command=LogIn><Login=\(loginTextField.text!)><Password=\(passwordTextField.text!)>")
}
```

And I want that `activityIndicator` running **BEFORE** start `SendRequest` method. But this didn't work. Why? `activityIndicator` running when `SendRequest` finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are blocking the main thread with your `SendRequest`. You have also scheduled your operation to start the indicator, but it's on the queue after the thing which is currently happening, so it isn't going to run until after you release the main thread.

So, don't put the indicator change into an operation, put the `SendRequest` into an operation and execute it on a queue that isn't main - i.e. a background thread. Then everything will work smoothly and the users will be happy.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand  your second paragraph. I delete indicator from operation `@IBAction func joinButtonTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.joinButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.resultLogIn.text = "Происходит проверка данных..."` that is right? What I must do with `SendRequest`?

Comment: run `SendRequest` on a background thread, don't block the main thread